# Merging many small projects into one multi-project while keeping history and branches in Git

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I have a number of small projects, each in its own repository. Now I need to have one Gradle multi-project build from all of the small projects. I have created a new Git repository, added required Gradle files and directory structure and hit a wall with merging. I have tried suggestions from other threads like subprojects and sub-tree but I need a little more:

Each project has two main branches - `master` and `develop`. Each has also a number of other feature branches each with its own unique name (no two names are the same across all projects).

I know how to add a subproject, merge `master` branches and keep the history of commits. I don't know how to keep the branch data. In other words I would like to:

1. Merge not only `master` but also `develop` branch across all projects and keep its history.
2. Keep all small feature branches.
3. Not do it by hand for each branch.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you merge `master` branches and when you have a single repo, you do

```
git checkout master
git merge myRemote/master
```

What about doing it in a loop over each repo / branch ?

For example:

```
#Retrieving master branches
git checkout master
for remote in $(git remote); do
  git merge $remote/master
done

#Retrieving develop branches
git checkout develop
for remote in $(git remote); do
  git merge $remote/develop
done

#Retrieving feature branches, using the fact that no two names are the same accross all projects
for remote in $(git remote); do
  for branch in $(git branch -a | grep $remote | sed 's#remotes/$remote/##'); do
    git checkout $remote/$branch
    git branch $branch
  done
done
```